# Live "Backup" or Disk Mirroring. Windows Server 2012

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, fileshare, backup-strategies

We are in position to decide to have 2 sites so when our Main Systems **(site1 -- which is Primary location for our businesses)** is down, so we have some virtual machines, file servers/file shares, SQL and Exchange in standby on other site **(site2 -- secondary location)**. So we have some sort of backup so we could possibly have whole company up and running so fast we can.

What i want to ask you guys is about "live backup" Servers/file shares.

Do Windows Server have some tools so we can create exactly same copy of file shares on site2. Like fail-over cluster or something? We want that site1 and site2 file shares will communicate and have some sort of contact so when user copy some pictures to Primary file share (**//fileshare1**), then the secondary fileshare (**//fileshare2**) or **Server**, will now that there was been some changes in primary server/fileshare, and it'll copy that picture to site2. Some sort of "live backup" or mirroring.

Do Windows Server have some options like this?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use replica of VM as a solution to start replicated VM on the second site during a Disaster Recovery Plan, then this is possible, available in Windows Server (2012 or later) with Hyper-V Replica. This feature has no additional costs, it's included in Windows Server Licence.

This feature allows to replicate VM with a RPO of 30 seconds / 5 minutes or 15 minutes (depending on what you need, your network speed..). VM on recovery site (site 2) are shutdown until you want to use Site 2.

More information on Hyper-V Replica : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134172%28v=ws.11%29.aspx

More over, in Windows Server 2016 (that will be release in H2 CY16) there is also a feature to replicate a Windows Volume between 2 serveurs (or 2 clusters) : Storage Replica

More information on Storage Replica : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt126104.aspx